# How do I change the background color of button after clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, axios, thymeleaf

I need to change the background color of the button from dark to green

```
<button class="btn btn-dark" id="btn" th:attr="onclick=|vote('${listAnswer.answer_id}','+1')|"><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" ></i>UpVote</button>
```

I tried to changed the button's background color from dark to green using following code. It does not work. Please help me

```
function vote(answerId,rateValue){

         alert(rateValue);

         axios.post('/saveRatings?answerId=' + answerId + '&rateValue=' + rateValue, {


         })
         .then(function(response){


      document.getElementById("btn").style.background-color='green';

         })

         }
```

Comment: `.style.background-color` should be camel case `.style.backgroundColor`

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript property names cannot contain the `-` character because this is an [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_negation).

Due to this, CSS properties must be accessed with [camelCase syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference).

Instead of :

```
document.getElementById("btn").style.background-color = 'green';
```

Use this :

```
document.getElementById("btn").style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

Answer (score 1):

After you have clicked a button it's state becomes "active" and you can use css to change the color of the button to whatever you want. All you need to do is add a css rule using the ":active" selector.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-button-style-hover-color-and-background/
Basically:

```
button:active { color: green; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
<button class="btn btn-dark" id="btn" th:attr="onclick=|vote('${listAnswer.answer_id}','+1')|"><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" ></i>UpVote</button>
```

JS

```
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function onClick() {
  btn.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  btn.style.color = '(Color whatever you want)';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

also instead of `document.getElementById("btn").style.background-color` you can use `document.getElementById("btn").style['background-color']`